# suggestions for practicing Generators(python)

Tags: python, generator

I understand the concept behind Generators and why one would choose that over lists.., but i'm struggling so much with getting quality practice by actually implementing them in my coding..Any suggestions on the type of problems I should play around with? I did the 'Fibonacci' code already but would like to practice with other types that would put generators to good use.--thanks--

Comment: I find it a bit weird to "practice generators". Usually you master coding techniques, by using these in real life. Furthermore generators are not always the best design decision. Instead of looking for exercises on generators, I would implement code challanges, etc. and use generators where applicable.

Comment: ah.understood thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one: implement a generator that reads chunks from a large file or a big database (so big that it wouldn't fit into the memory). Alternatively, consider a stream of infinitely many values as input.

As you might already have learned, this is a common use case in real world applications:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html

> With a list comprehension, you get back a Python list; [...] Generator expressions return an iterator that computes the values as necessary, not needing to materialize all the values at once. This means that list comprehensions aren’t useful if you’re working with iterators that return an infinite stream or a very large amount of data. Generator expressions are preferable in these situations.

http://naiquevin.github.io/python-generators-and-being-lazy.html

> Now you may ask how does this differ from an ordinary list and what is the use of all this anyway? The key difference is that the generator gives out new values on the fly and doesn't keep the elements in memory.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

> The performance improvement from the use of generators is the result of the lazy (on demand) generation of values, which translates to lower memory usage. Furthermore, we do not need to wait until all the elements have been generated before we start to use them. This is similar to the benefits provided by iterators, but the generator makes building iterators easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and information, much appreciated.